# Converting datetime format in pandas for timeseries analysis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series data. However, the date format is `%dd.%mm.%yyy` ( i.e : 01.01.2020). ( pandas data type is `object`). 
I want to do time series analysis.  how can I change the format so that I can do time series analysis?

I have tried the following code.

```
df["booking_day_new"] = pd.to_datetime(df.booking_day.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

also

```
df['booking_day'] = df['booking_day'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['booking_day'])` suffices

Comment: @Erfan - It was my oops, sorry.